# Get value of MySQL table right after form submitted

Tags: php

Is there a way to get the value of a MySQL table, right after the form has been submitted? In fact,  with each new form submitted, there is a unique code posted in the table, but I need that code to rederict the user to a specefic URL, that contain the unique code.

Comment: Possible repost of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477502/get-the-last-inserted-row-id-with-sql-statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the last MySQL-generated ID on the last inserted record by using `last_insert_id()`.  More information [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id).

```
INSERT INTO SomeTable (SomeColumn) VALUES ('SomeValue');
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Depending on which data access method you're using there may even be a PHP-visible function to do this for you.