# How can I get a newly inserted auto increment value?

Tags: mysql

Say a table T with a PRIMARY KEY `id`, I set it to AUTO INCREMENT.

I need to get the newly INSERTED id value for other operation, however, since it's the only PRIMARY KEY and AUTO INCREMENT, I don't how to do it.

Another SELECT with all other values in WHERE is valid in theory, but it's too slow.

Any better ideas?

Comment: The API client should be able to return the last inserted ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should you be checking [LAST_INSERT_ID()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) like

```
select LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Comment: Thank you, I am currently using this.

Answer (score 0):

Does this not work?

```
select max(id) from T;
```

Comment: Then please edit your original question to show a sample of the input you're processing and the output you would like to see.

Answer (score 0):

This will produce the last id without functions

```
SELECT id FROM t ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

By the way .. You should get the id after your insert statement from any MySQL api

Answer (score 0):

It obviously depends on what database engine you use.
If , like I suppose, We are speaking about MSSQL, a good practise is to return last id generated in the current transaction (or session). You could see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477502/get-the-last-inserted-row-id-with-sql-statement) for more info.

Anyway, you could calculate the max id, but whitout warranties if someone instert new row in the while.