# Auto generate and AutoIncrement ID in C# when trying to add new record to database

Tags: c#, sql-server, auto-increment

I'm using this code to select the maxID from a database table and each time I want to add a new record, the autogenerated ID is not the last one +1.

```
 public formularAddCompanie()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        try
        {
            string cs = "Data Source=CODRINMA\\CODRINMA;Initial Catalog=TrafficManager;Integrated Security=True";
            string select = "SELECT max(IDCompanie) FROM Companii";

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(select, con);
                SqlDataReader sda = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
                DataTable idmax = new DataTable("idmax");
                idmax.Load(sda);
                if (idmax.Rows[0][0].ToString().Trim() == "") { txtID.Text = "1"; }
                else { txtID.Text = (int.Parse(idmax.Rows[0][0] .ToString() + 1).ToString()); }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception er) { MessageBox.Show(er.Message); }
    }
```

The table from where the selection is made, looks like this:

```
IDCompany   Name   Address   City  RegNo
1           A      Street    NY    123
```

Each time I want to add a new record, the autogenerated ID is like this: 11, 111, 1111. It takes the last ID and add another 1 next to it. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you aware that Sql Server has IDENTITY columns and these columns could generate for you the autoincrement value that you are trying to simulate with the MAX function? (a secure way to failure if you have more than one concurrent user)

Comment: In addition to what @Steve mentions, this will fail if you have more than one user using the system at the same time, as their two instances of the client can easily generate the same ID.

Comment: @Steve - I know about the IDENTITY property, but I don't know exactly how to link it to my app so I chose this way..

Comment: And you have choosen a wrong path. MAX cannot guarantee uniqueness of the number because another user could call the same function from another PC and get the same value. The correct way is to use an IDENTITY column, do not let the user see or change the IDCompany and when you execute the INSERT and want to know what is the IDCompany calculated by the database use SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29994945/how-to-get-id-of-row-that-is-insertingnew/29995065#29995065) is related to your problem

Comment: @Steve - I got your point, but at the same time it's less probable that two users that want to add a new record, generate the same ID, complete all the fields at the same time and save the data at the same moment.. it has to be a delay, even for a 0.00001 second. On the other hand, this app is only for personal use, not commercial, but I take your answer as a tip for the future, just in case. Thanks for your time answering my question!

Comment: Well, not a big deal then. Just another tip. You don't need all that code to just retrieve the MAX of your table. ExecuteScalar will be a lot faster here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interestingly, note that

```
string a = "The meaning of life is " + 42;
```

converts 42 to a string, creating the result

```
a == "The meaning of life is 42"
```

Look at this code:

```
(int.Parse(idmax.Rows[0][0] .ToString() + 1).ToString()); }
```

You are converting idmax.Rows[0][0] to a string and adding +1 to the end *of the string* rather than to an integer value.  Try

```
(int.Parse(idmax.Rows[0][0].ToString()) + 1).ToString(); }
```

Note that `idmax.Rows[0][0]` should already have an integer in it (as pointed out in the comments).  If that's the case, you can simplify to

```
(idmax.Rows[0][0] + 1).ToString(); }
```

Comment: Why `toInt(toString(x))` at all?

Comment: @user2864740: Fair point.  I wasn't making an assumption about what is actually in idmax.Rows[0][0] and trying to keep things as close to his original code as possible, just highlighting the critical change.  However there is already an int there.  I'll add on to my answer to point this out.

Answer (score 2):

`idmax.Rows[0][0].ToString() + 1` produces `string`, not `int`.

You can try

```
txtID.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(idmax.Rows[0][0]) + 1).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this snippet:

Convert Your `String` into `Int`. `String` with `+` operator will con-cat and with `int` it will add numbers.

```
if (idmax.Rows[0][0].ToString().Trim() == "") { txtID.Text = "1"; }

else { 
txtID.Text =  Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(idmax.Rows[0][0] .ToString())+1); }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just add this because it seems that none cares about the weakness of the code posted by the poster.
First the MAX function is not reliable if you want to find the next autoincrement value that will be assigned to an ID column. Concurrency could wreak havoc with any schema that use MAX. Just suppose that another user has already retrieved the MAX for its own INSERT operation, then depending on the relative speed of the two computers you or the other user will insert a duplicate value for the IDCompany field.

The only correct way to do this common task is to use the IDENTITY property for the column IDCompany and when you need to insert a new record you should write something like this

```
try
{
    string insert  = "INSERT INTO Companii (Name,Address,City,RegNo) 
                      VALUES(@name,@address,@city,@regno);
                      SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insert, con))
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtBoxCity.Text;
        .... and on for the other parameters ....
        int companyID = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        ... work with the just added company if required
    }
}
catch (Exception er) 
{ MessageBox.Show(er.Message); }
```

[SCOPE_IDENTITY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) will return the last identity value inserted into an identity column in the same scope and in this context scope means the connection used by your command.

In any case, if the MAX approach is still required then the code could be simplified a lot using a modified query and [SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of building an SqlDataReader, filling a datatable, trying to parse the result with ifs

```
string getMax = @"select COALESCE(MAX(IDCompany), 0) + 1 AS maxPlusOne 
                  from Companii"
using(SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(.....))
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(getMax, cnn))
{
    cnn.Open();
    int nextCompanyID = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
}
```

[The COALESCE function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) checks the result of the MAX function and if it is NULL returns the second parameter (here 0), then just increment by 1 to get the next MAX directly from the database. ExecuteScalar will do the call returning just the `maxPlusOne` alias field

Comment: Simply don't understand why this wasn't the obvious answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try This one, my id format is USR001.The code will generate auto id based on the last id inside the database. If the last id in the database is USR001, the the code will generate USR002 and put the id to the textbox

```
con.Open();
            string sqlQuery = "SELECT TOP 1 kode_user from USERADM order by kode_user desc";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, con);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                string input = dr["kode_user"].ToString();
                string angka = input.Substring(input.Length - Math.Min(3, input.Length));
                int number = Convert.ToInt32(angka);
                number += 1;
                string str = number.ToString("D3");

                txtKodeUser.Text = "USR" + str;
            }
            con.Close();
```