# Sql retreive actual Insert ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that holds client informations

```
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, // Primary Key
[Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[User] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Adrss] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Connected] [int] NOT NULL,
```

then i have a `Stored Precedure`

```
 procedure AddClient

    @Name Varchar(50),
    @User Varchar(50),
    @Adrss Varchar(50),
    @Connected Int

    as

        Insert into Clients(
        Name,
        User,
        Adrss,
        Connected)
        Values(
        @Name,
        @User,
        @adrss
        @Connected)
```

So The Field `ID` is auto increment I want to retreive it's value while inserting i want to return the insert position

**Note** 1 :  I'm searching for another method than the `Max(ID +1)`

**Note** 2 : Please note that if any row is deleted the value will continue increment the Deleted ID won't be regenerated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends what DB you are using, if MySQL you can use http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php for PHP

`SCOPE_IDENTITY()` Can be used for SQL-Server

Here is a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9477528/895169

Comment: i'm using Sql Server

Comment: @Buffer_z Updated