# SQL - Attain Previous Transaction Informaiton

Tags: sql-server, subquery

Recently got my golden certificate for completing SQL Server Implementation... I am officially allowed to add 1 and 1. Still a noob and need some serious help :-).

I have really tried hard to find the solution to this,
previously using DAX in Excel it work out perfectly.

Table with Refueling Transactions:
File (Source Information); FleetNo_PT (Asset Number); Date_Refuel; Quantity; Reading (KM_Odometer)

Requirement:
**Show Current and Previous Transaction Information** on a Single Line AND then calculated **results** Days Between Refueling; KM_Driven; Consumption_Rate (KM_Driven divide by Quantity)

I have tried many different way but non are successful

Comment: Does the row have a createdAt field or a identity column? You could use those to get the latest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477502/get-the-last-inserted-row-id-with-sql-statement

Comment: @maartenDev,That did not solve my problem, in fact that whole thing created more confusion

Comment: The real solution here is LEAD and LAG function, its far simpler solution than the proposed solution.

To attain the previous or next transaction detail use 
https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=sql+previous+transaction+value