Uniqueidentifier not working in stored procedure?
I'm trying to establish a NEWID() (copy) and getting error that uniqueidentifier is incompatible with int - what am I doing wrong?
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ReleasedVersionCopy]
AS
    INSERT INTO Template (Template_Name, DeptID, TemplateOwnerID, Created_Date, Last_Update, Released_Date, IsPublished, IsDeleted)
        SELECT 
            Template_Name + ' - Copy3', DeptID, TemplateOwnerID, 
            Created_Date, Last_Update, Released_Date, 
            IsPublished, IsDeleted 
        FROM 
            Template
        WHERE 
            TemplateID = 2

DECLARE @TemplateID uniqueidentifier;
SET @TemplateID = NEWID()

INSERT INTO Panel (Panel_Name, TemplateID, Panel_Order)
    SELECT Panel_Name, @TemplateID, Panel_Order
    FROM Panel
    WHERE TemplateID = 2

DECLARE @Cntr INTEGER = 0;

WHILE @Cntr < 5
BEGIN;
    SET @Cntr = @Cntr + 1;

    DECLARE @PanelID uniqueidentifier;
    SET @PanelID = NEWID()

    INSERT INTO Field (Field_Name, PanelID, FieldTypeID, PlacementH, Field_Order)
        SELECT Field_Name, @PanelID, FieldTypeID, PlacementH, Field_Order
        FROM Field
        INNER JOIN Panel ON Field.PanelID = Panel.PanelID
        INNER JOIN Template ON Panel.TemplateID = Template.TemplateID
        WHERE Template.TemplateID = 2
    END;

This is the error I'm getting:

Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Procedure ReleasedVersionCopy, Line 16 [Batch Start Line 7]
Operand type clash: uniqueidentifier is incompatible with int
Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Procedure ReleasedVersionCopy, Line 32 [Batch Start Line 7]
Operand type clash: uniqueidentifier is incompatible with int

Here is Template
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Template]
(
    [TemplateID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Template_Name] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [DeptID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TemplateOwnerID] [nvarchar](6) NOT NULL,
    [Created_Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Last_Update] [datetime] NULL,
    [Released_Date] [datetime] NULL,
    [IsPublished] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsDeleted] [bit] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Template] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([TemplateID] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Template]  WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Template_Dept] 
        FOREIGN KEY([DeptID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Dept] ([DeptID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Template] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Template_Dept]
GO

Here is Panel
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Panel]
(
    [PanelID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Panel_Name] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [TemplateID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Panel_Order] [int] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Panel] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PanelID] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Panel]  WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Panel_Template] 
        FOREIGN KEY([TemplateID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Template] ([TemplateID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Panel] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Panel_Template]
GO


You really should add SET XACT_ABORT ON; and wrap it in a TRANSACTION.

We need to see the CREATE TABLE statements for those tables of yours: Template and Panel.

Your INSERT INTO dbo.Panel inserts into the  TemplateId INT column - but the value you're trying to insert is DECLARE @TemplateID uniqueidentifier; SET @TemplateID = NEWID() - that's most definitely never going to work !!

Change the TemplateID column from int to uniqueidentifier.

@IanBoyd It's far less work to just change the uniqueidentifier-typed variables to int.

thank you for the help....just so i'm clear would i change  dbo.Template.TemplateID to uniqueidentifier and dbo.Panel.TemplateID to uniqueidentifier also?

Dai, i did try changing uniqueidentifier to int but got the same error

in your table the column is IDENTITY(1,1) is an INT. When you insert into the table with this column, you should not specify the value for this column... it will be added automatically by the autoincrement.
However, NEWID() and UNIQUEIDENTIFIER are varchars. Decide what you want.

@Yoav24 NEWID() and UNIQUEIDENTIFIER are GUID types in SQL Server, not varchar.

@Dai yes good point. they have output like '0E984725-C51C-4BF4-9960-E1C80E27ABA0' ... anyway very different than INT

Fyi SSMS is only a UI, it's not typically relevant to SQL Server questions.

keeping the design as INT what would be an alternative solution to NEWID() and int

I think this is what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477502/get-the-last-inserted-row-id-with-sql-statement#9477528

Btw - is there a reason you haven't "accepted" an answer to any of your previous questions?

Taking this as an example:
[TemplateID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL

A value is assigned to this column as you are using identity, and this is defined as an int.
To allow this to work you either need to create a new column in the table schemas of a uniqueidentifier or change the table structure to make templateid a guid.
I personally would review why you are trying to use a GUID, but assuming you still need it, add in a new column to accommodate it as when you start to look at indexing having an integer based pk will be beneficial.

I suspect the opposite is true, OP was trying to use the new, int, Id but didn't know how to obtain it.
