# How to insert a new record which has a auto increment number as primary key?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, exception

For example, I have the following Table:

**CustomerInfo**

```
cus_id: auto increment, int, is Identity
cus_name: nvarchar
```

If I use the follow codes to insert the record "Peter",

```
string name = "Peter";
DataContext DC = new DataContext();
CustomerInfo newCustomer = new CustomerInfo();
newCustomer.cus_name = name;

DC.CustomerInfos.InsertOnSubmit(newCustomer);
DC.SubmitChanges();
```

The following error returns,

> Can't perform Create, Update, or Delete operations on 'Table(CustomerInfo)' because it has no primary key.

Do I need to self-define the `cus_id` or any other solutions? Thanks!

Comment: Tags in title are not necessary really. Thanks.

Comment: `cus_id` is not a Primary Key, or at least that's what the error says

Comment: Could you show the definition of the `CustomerInfo` class?

Comment: Sorry, it is not a PK but is identity. I have changed it in my question.

Comment: @Pang you'll need to add a Primary Key to the table; that's the way LinqToSql works. And generally [this is good practice](http://stackoverflow.com/a/840182/390819) anyway

Comment: Hi, I have set the cus_id as primary key but the other error comes out: Incorrect AutoSync specification for member 'cus_id'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all LINQ-To-SQL needs primary keys in order to be able to do Inserts and Updates, so you probably have to add the Primary Key in your table.

Now, because it is an auto incremented identity column, in your dbml, you have to select the column "cus_id" of the "CustomerInfo" table and go to the properties and set the following:

- **Auto Generated Value** : True
- **Auto-Sync** : OnInsert

This will ensure that when you insert a new row it will get a new id.

Answer (score 1):

naratting from answer 1 of [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293426/whats-the-difference-between-a-primary-key-and-identity) you'll have to make cus_id as primary key too.
you can also try to do following

```
CREATE TABLE Customers
(
cus_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
cus_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (cus_id)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error to. As far as I manged to fix it was to add a primary key.
This code made me a primary key and made it autoincrement. Maybe it's what you are looking for?
(When you create the table)

```
columnname bigint IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT pkcolumnname PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```